# iOS: How to generate a video file via images/audio?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want use some images and audio files to generate a movie (the image sequence)

anyone can give a tip?

Comment: Do you need to actually create a movie file? Or do you just want to present images on the screen in sync with an audio recording?  The second of these would be simpler :-)

Comment: movie..... it could be play on other video player also can be upload to video site ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it could be done using AVAssetWriter

[ASSETWriterInput for making Video from UIImages on Iphone Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983882/assetwriterinput-for-making-video-from-uiimages-on-iphone-issues)

hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

This is a demo: http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/01/create-movie-from-array-of-images/

use the same way : AVAssetWriter.
Perhaps more useful.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.