# AVAssetwriter writing failed

Tags: ios, avassetwriter

I am writing a little video-editing app on iOS. I followed the most rated answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983882/assetwriterinput-for-making-video-from-uiimages-on-iphone-issues) to use AVAssetwriter, but the writing failed in the end. When I got into the complete callback in

```
[videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){}];
```

I got this error from the videoWriter.error every time.

```
[0] (null)  "NSUnderlyingError" : domain: "NSOSStatusErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709539204  
[1] (null)  "NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion" : "Try saving again."   
[2] (null)  "NSLocalizedDescription" : "Cannot Save"
```

The URL I tried to save the image is built by

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"processedVideo.mp4";
NSString *filenameFull = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSURL *videoOutURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filenameFull];
```

So it is like

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA2BF494-9093-4034-8E6F-0FC177C9F2E3/Documents/processedVideo.mp4
```

Any suggestions on what did I get wrong?

Comment: It turned out that the issue was manipulating the frame buffers mistakenly . When generating and filling each frame buffer, I accidentally accessed memory beyond boundary but it issued no error until finishing and compressing begin.

Answer (score 2):

if already a file exist in saving directory then asset writer give writing error. first check if the if there is any file exists . you can remove previous existing file by this.

```
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath: filenameFull error:&error];
```

or you can write file with different file name . hope it will works